# Collection Editor at runtime

Tags: .net, propertygrid, collectioneditor

I'm working on an application to edit name/value pairs using a property grid. 
Some of the properties in my class file are ListDictionary collections. Is there 
an Editor attribute that I can apply at the property declaration that will make the
Collection Editor work at runtime? If not, is it possible to inherit from
ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor for use at runtime? I need to be able to add,
delete and edit the collection values.
Thanks alot,
Terry

Comment: I think that this article explains what you need: [How to Edit and Persist Collections with CollectionEditor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dzcollectioneditor.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

from codeproject article [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dzcollectioneditor.aspx][1]

> There are three requirements that a
>   collection should meet in order to be
>   successfully persisted with the
>   CollectionEditor:
>
> 1. First, the collection must implement the IList interface
>      (inheriting from
>      System.Collections.CollectionBase is
>      in most of the cases the best option).
> 2. Second, it must have an Indexer (Item in VB.NET) property. The type of
>      this property is used by the
>      CollectionEditor to determine the
>      default type of the instances that
>      will add to the collection.
>
>    To better understand how this works, take a look at GetItemType()
>      function of the
>      CustomCollectionEditorForm:
>
>    protected virtual Type GetItemType(IList coll)
>        {
>            PropertyInfo pi= coll.GetType().GetProperty("Item",
>                                                   new Type[]{typeof(int)});
>            return pi.PropertyType
>        }
> 3. Third, the collection class must implement one or both of the following
>      methods: Add and AddRange. Although
>      IList interface has an Add member and
>      CollectionBase implements IList, you
>      still have to implement an Add method
>      for your collection, given that
>      CollectionBase declares an explicit
>      member implementation of the IList’s
>      Add member. The designer serializes
>      the collection according to what
>      method you have implemented. If you
>      have implemented both, the AddRange is
>      preferred.

In this article you'll find everything you need to implement your collection on the property grid